# GPT Commit Generator for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, commit, chatgpt-api

There are cool Visual Studio Code extensions for generating automatic commit messages using ChatGPT API. Like these...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MichaelCurrin.auto-commit-msg
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarlMoritzWildenhain.gpt-commit-generator

Is there any extension like this for Visual Studio 2022. I couldn't find any. If not is there a way around it? I cannot use Github Copilot because my repo is in Gitlab. Maybe using [this](https://github.com/RomanHotsiy/commitgpt)?